# debugger in Clion 2016.2 EAP is not like before

Tags: c, debugging, clion

I just upgraded to the latest early access of Clion and the debugger is not working for me. It worked in earlier versions. Now I can run a minimal program and get the expected output.

```
/home/dac/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/cliontest-77d7a571/77d7a571/Debug/cliontest
hello
Process finished with exit code 0
```

But the debugger doesn't seem to work? I add breakpoints but there is no output and no break, the program just exits. Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in this version [2016.2 EAP build 162.1120.17](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/CLION/Early+Access+Program) of Clion? The debugger used to work better in version 2016.1, even though I got an error there that I'm trying to see if it is still in the latest version. What I got when debugging before was "Cannot collect variable" for certain variable and it is this error that I am investigating if it is still in newer versions. But now I have two problems: I can't even get the debugger to work in this newer version. It's like the debugger is just "silent".

```
/home/dac/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/cliontest-77d7a571/77d7a571/Debug/cliontest
During startup program exited normally.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

[image]

If I manually navigate in the shell to the generated executable, then it is runnable but I want to use the debugger.

### Update

I opened an issue for this problem at Jetbrains https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-7132

Comment: Why not ask [JetBrains tech-support](https://www.jetbrains.com/support/) ?

Comment: @PaulR Yes. I'm actually going to open an issue for this in the youtracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved: The reason was that I was using my own custom shell that can't perform all shell functionality. When I switched to bash shell, then everything worked.